# ASP.NET MVC get dropdown list value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, drop-down-menu

In ASP.NET MVC, how can I get a selected dropdown list value from a posted form?

Comment: Check it here might help you.
[DropeDown List](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class MyController
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(string DropDownListName)
    {

    }
}
```

This will do the line of code in MasterMind's answer for you. Which method you want to use depends on your situation. Either is fine in my opinion.

If all your possible selected values are numbers you can also do this:

```
public class MyController
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(int DropDownListName)
    {

    }
}
```

It will then convert the string of the selected value into an integer for you.

Comment: thank you so much @Garry, wasted half day to get desired id from database list, at last this solution worked, for other options for binding databse table with dropdownlist check [this](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2918/working-with-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc), hope helps someone

Answer (score 4):

```
public class MyController
{
    public ActionResult MyAction (FormCollection form)
    {
        string value = form["DropDownListName"];
    }
}
```